# Geocoding and Search API: Qualified Query does not return street address when used with free-form search query

Tags: here-api

I am trying to geocode addresses using the HERE Geocoding and Search API. My workflow involves a free-form text address that I am augmenting with additional information about Country, State, County using the `qq` attributes. I am following the model described in the [Hybrid Queries](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-api/code-geocode-hybrid.html) section of the documentation.

However, if I specify the county field as a Qualified Query using the `qq` parameter, the result is not returning a street address. Using the same query without a `county` parameter accurately returns the street address.

E.g.:

The following query does not return a street address:

[https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=[apiKey]&qq=country%3DUSA%3Bstate%3DLA%3Bcounty%3DAscension&q=42077%20CHURCHPOINT%20RD,%20GONZALES](https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=%5BapiKey%5D&qq=country%3DUSA%3Bstate%3DLA%3Bcounty%3DAscension&q=42077%20CHURCHPOINT%20RD,%20GONZALES)

However, removing the `county` field from the qualified query returns a street address:

[https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=[apiKey]&qq=country%3DUSA%3Bstate%3DLA%3B&q=42077%20CHURCHPOINT%20RD,%20GONZALES](https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?apiKey=%5BapiKey%5D&qq=country%3DUSA%3Bstate%3DLA%3B&q=42077%20CHURCHPOINT%20RD,%20GONZALES)

What's also weird is that looking at the response to the second query, the county is correctly included in the address body so the value I am including in the `county` field matches what's on the backend but the query isn't returning the street address.

Is there anything I can do here to force the API to return a street address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there might be an issue of matching the county names in some specificed locations. I tried locations in CA, matching county name worked without a problem. The issue has been forwarded to our development team. Their analysis result will be shared here later.

In the meantime, you could just drop "county" from qq as a walkaround.

Comment: Confirmed the issue with development team. The issue has been fixed on the new release. I checked just now, the issue is not observed anymore.